# Activating Inactive Same-Name Different-Tag Game Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

For some reason, I cannot change the name of a game object (an avatar) but I need to have 2 different versions of it and activate them in code.

So, duplicating the avatar is not an option, but I still need to create an identical one and make a change in editor mode, so that based on a condition, whether **one** or **the other** is chosen.

It occurred to me, now that changing the name is not possible, perhaps I can give **the other** a different **tag** and activate the right one based on the selected scenario.

So, I checked out a few manual docs and some forum posts and came up with the following 3 alternatives to place in my `Start()` but none works:

```
void Start()
{
    if ( GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("John") )
        gameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("John").SetActive(true);

    if ( GameObject.FindWithTag("John") )
        gameObject.FindWithTag("John").SetActive(true);
}
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong and how I can achieve this: **find an object that is not active** (**from among 2 inactive objects with the same name but different tags**: one `untagged` and the other tagged as, say, `John`)

Comment: ***NOTE*** - one line of your code was very confusing, as it was referring to "this" game object. I edited it out to avoid confsuion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't be easier, just assign them to ***different variables***

```
public GameObject johnCharacterOnLeft;
public GameObject johnCharacterWhoJoinsLater;

void Start()
  {
  johnCharacterOnLeft.SetActive(true);
  johnCharacterOnLeft.Whatever(true);
  johnCharacterOnLeft.Whatever(true);
  johnCharacterOnLeft.Whatever(true);
  johnCharacterWhoJoinsLater.SetActive(false);
  johnCharacterWhoJoinsLater.Whatever(false);
  johnCharacterWhoJoinsLater.Whatever(false);
  ...
  }
```

Note, as a rule when you are learning, ***do not*** use Find. It's that simple. Use public variables and drag to connect in the inspector.

[image]

(If anyone reading does not yet know how to drag to connect in the inspector, check any basic [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/communicating-between-components-gameobjects).)

---

## If you do want to find *all* objects with a certain *tag*:

```
GameObject[] allCats;
allCats = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cat");
foreach (GameObject g in allCats)
 Debug.Log("I found one, name is: " +g.name);
```

If you want to find one of those *with a certain name* you have to search through them all..

```
GameObject[] allCats;
allCats = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cat");
foreach (GameObject g in allCats)
 {
 Debug.Log("I found one, name is: " +g.name);
 if ( g.name == "Felix" )
   {
   Debug.Log("I did find Felix the cat");
   g.Whatever ...
   }
```

---

## If you do want to find *all* objects with a certain *name*...

It's very important to understand that

## *...you just can't do that in Unity - it simply makes no sense.*

Life's life that - `Find` is a hack you should never really use anyway, other than in rare situations.  If you (for some reason?) need to "find" all game objects with a certain name, you have to simply *look through every single thing in the scene* (which is not particularly easy to do). You can easily google this. But there is, absolutely, no reason you would ever do this.

Note that, *just one example* .. say you had a number of "cat" thing in your scene. ***Very simply - nothing more complicated than this - you would have them all in the same "folder"***. (That is to say, all under the same holder game object.) That is just one incredibly simple approach to utterly avoid the sort of problem you're having.

Again there *literally is no way* to find "all game objects with the same name" - the `Find` call is a hack that should never have been in Unity; they explicitly don't have

---

## And most importantly don't forget...Find doesn't work if inactive!

The `Find` call is a hack that should never have been in Unity: always remember **it does not even work** on inactive objects. Inasmuch as they threw in a "find name" concept, it's probably for the best that it doesn't work on inactive objects: but the whole thing is a shambles - just don't use "find", ever.

Particularly as a beginner ***just drag in the inspector*** - it's honestly that easy.  (And again, in almost all cases your stuff will start inactive, so of course you have to do that since you can't "find" inactive stuff.)

(And a note - don't forget that if you're simply finding a "boss" type script, say your `Scores` or `SoundEffects`, never use find.  Just do [this easy idiom](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/46285/view.html). )

Comment: Thanks Joe. I tried the first part, but neither is found. Could it be due to the fact that they are both initially inactive?

Comment: Of course I cannot use the public `GameObject johnCharacterOnLeft;` way, because they are both named the same thing, but the tags are different.

Comment: Hi @Jtech.  I can absolutely assure you that you use `public GameObject johnCharacterOnLeft`  Copy my code in to your script.  **DON'T FORGET TO DRAG THE CONNECTION IN THE INSPECTOR**.  works ok now?

Comment: hi @Jtech.  I included an image showing how you "drag to the inspector". working for you?

Comment: And remember: you can't find inactive gameobjects by tag.

Comment: GREAT!  bring on the next problem!  you raised a good issue here, the "find" concept in Unity is very confusing, and I couldn't find a good answer yet posted here about it